# Calling a javascript function using an ASP.Net button control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var geocoder;
            var map;
            var latlngstr;
            function initialize() {
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
            }


            function codeAddress() {
                var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                        latlngstr = results[0].geometry.location;

                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: results[0].geometry.location
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                    }
                });


                document.getElementById('lat').value = latlngstr.lat();
                document.getElementById('lng').value = latlngstr.lng();
            }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body onload="initialize()">
          <form  id="form1" runat="server">

        <div>
            <input id="address" type="text" value="sydney" />
            <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
            <input id="lat" type="text" />

            <input id="lng" type="text" />
        </div>


            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
                  Text="Button" EnableViewState="False" 
                  ViewStateMode="Disabled" OnClientClick="javascript:return codeAddress();"/>



          <div id="map-canvas"></div>
       </form>   
      </body>
    </html>
```

I want to call the function `codeAddress`. When I call this function with an html button, the button with the value `Geocode`, it works fine. But when I call that function with an ASP.Net button the 'else' part is executed and it produces no result.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxjscript/thread/3efc7bf9-730f-47d0-bc9c-7a3550cf1282/

Answer (score 0):

I infer that what you want to do is use the geocoding code to obtain the latitude and longitude and then post back with those.

Rather than make one button do client-side code and (at the same time) post back, I'd keep the HTML button but start a form post from your JavaScript code, once the fields have been set:

```
            document.getElementById('lat').value = latlngstr.lat();
            document.getElementById('lng').value = latlngstr.lng();
            document.forms[0].submit();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Ann but I want to call the function on the click of asp.net button control only....I passed the function name in the onclientclick attribute of the button but it execute the else part of the function....

Comment: This may or may not be the problem, but the syntax you used is incorrect.  Rather than `javascript:return codeAddress();` it should be `codeAddress()`, like with the HTML button.

Comment: thanks for the reply Ann....my problem is solved...i have added the UseSubmitBehavior="false" attribute to button control and now it is working fine...